# VBA in excel to compare columns with different cases

Tags: vba, excel

I am comparing the columns with Dates and numbers. I have in total 8 columns (A-H). 
Column A and B contains numbers. (in somecases column B is empty). 
Column D(sdate) and E(Ldate) contains Dates. ( in some cases column E is empty).

I have 4 cases with me now.

Case 1 is if sdate < 2 weeks of Ldate, then print ontime.

case2  is sdate > 4weeks of Ldate, print delay.

case 3 is sdate is <4weeks and > 2weeks of Ldate, then print Project remaning.with case 3, there is another condition, that, if column A, B and D are present, but no date in column E, it should still print remaining.

case4: column A contains numbers, column B has no numbers, Column D has date and Column E has no date then , it should be left blank.

2 experts of the Forum , guided me to achieve the criteria, but with the below code, there is an error that, it doesnt not satistfy case4 .

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim zWeeks As Double, zcolour As Long
    Dim Ztext As String

    Set ws = Sheets("Preparation Sheet")

    With ws
        lRow = .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To lRow


            zWeeks = DateDiff("ww", .Range("E" & i).Value, .Range("D" & i).Value)

            If .Range("A" & i).Value <> "" And .Range("B" & i).Value <> "" And .Range("E" & i).Value = "" Then
                Ztext = "remaining"
                zcolour = vbYellow
                Cells(i, 7) = "Yellow"
            ElseIf zWeeks < 2 Then
                Ztext = " on time"
                zcolour = vbGreen
                Cells(i, 7) = "Green"
            ElseIf zWeeks > 4 Then
                Ztext = "delayed"
                zcolour = vbRed
                Cells(i, 7) = "Red"
                ElseIf zWeeks > 2 < 4 Then
                Ztext = "remaining"
                zcolour = vbYellow
                Cells(i, 7) = "Yellow"

            End If


            With .Range("F" & i)
                .Value = Ztext
                .Interior.Color = zcolour
            End With
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

[image: I Need cases like this]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a new condition after the first one, which check if value on Col.B and E are blanks.

```
    ElseIf .Range("B" & i).value = "" And .Range("E" & i).value = "" Then
      GoTo nextrow
```

Then add the label before the end of the loop. This will skip the other condition and move to the next row:

```
nextrow:
    Next i
```

Comment: ya. this is what exactly i Need .. :) thanks a Ton to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add these lines before end if

```
ElseIf IsNumeric(Range("A" & i).Value) And (Not IsNumeric(Range("A" & i).Value)) And IsDate(Range("D" & i).Value) And Range("E" & i).Value = "" Then
Ztext = ""
zcolour = vbYellow
Cells(i, 7) = "Yellow"
```

Comment: it still dint satisfy condition 4. I have numbers in column A and no numbers in B, D has date and E has no date, in this case, it should be left blank. But the code prints Project delay.

Comment: Can you upload the file?

Comment: ya i will do it.

Comment: i have edited my question and have added an Image . If your not able to view the Image, Please imform me. @ahmed Abdel Khalek

Comment: I can see the image very well

Comment: So, A contain a number even if one digit? 
Because C312321 is a string value and not numeric
That confuses me.

Comment: I dint get you . sorry ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147248/discussion-between-mikz-and-ahmed-abdelkhalek).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Note: not tested

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim zWeeks As Double, zcolour As Long
    Dim Ztext As String

    Set ws = Sheets("Preparation Sheet")

    With ws
        lRow = .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To lRow
                lDate  = .Range("E" & i).Value
                sDate= .Range("D" & i).Value
            zWeeks = DateDiff("ww",sDate , lDate)

            If .Range("A" & i).Value <> "" And .Range("B" & i).Value <> "" And .Range("E" & i).Value = "" Then
                Ztext = "remaining"
                zcolour = vbYellow
                Cells(i, 7) = "Yellow"
            ElseIf .Range("A" & i).Value <>"" And .Range("B" & i).Value = "" And IsDate(sDate) And Ldate = "" Then
                Ztext = ""
                zcolour = vbYellow
                Cells(i, 7) = "Yellow"
            ElseIf zWeeks < 2 Then
                Ztext = " on time"
                zcolour = vbGreen
                Cells(i, 7) = "Green"
            ElseIf zWeeks > 4 Then
                Ztext = "delayed"
                zcolour = vbRed
                Cells(i, 7) = "Red"
            ElseIf zWeeks > 2 < 4 Then
                Ztext = "remaining"
                zcolour = vbYellow
                Cells(i, 7) = "Yellow"

            End If


            With .Range("F" & i)
                .Value = Ztext
                .Interior.Color = zcolour
            End With
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this, still the case4 is not satisfied. It prints delay. But according to the case, it should leave it as it as blank

Comment: I tried with the updated ans, it seems to be changing my cases. It printing on time everywhere, I have attached an Image, which i want the Output to look like, before the edit, the cases were proper except the Case4.